# Kivy define background color of label

Tags: python, kivy, kivy-language

I have trouble defining the background color for various objects (in this example labels) in the Kivy language for Python. The attached code creates a box layout, where each box has a certain background color.

1. How can this code be adapted so that I can define the size of the certain label via a variable, rather than hard code it. Best would be if we could come up with a solution like this:

```
    ForeignLanguage = ColoredLabel(..., size = (a,b))
```

2. My code appears quite complicated to me. Is it possible to set the background color ob a label in a more easy way, like Label(..., background_color = (1,1,1,1))?

```
    from kivy.app import App
    from kivy.uix.boxlayout import BoxLayout
    from kivy.uix.label import Label
    from kivy.properties import ListProperty
    from kivy.lang import Builder
    from kivy.core.window import Window


    kv = '''
    <ColoredLabel>:
        size: (self.size_x,self.size_y)
        pos: (0,0) # no effect
        background_color:
        canvas.before:
            Color:
                rgba: self.background_color
            Rectangle:
                pos: self.pos
                size: (self.size_x,self.size_y)
        '''

    Builder.load_string(kv)

    class ColoredLabel(Label):
        background_color = ListProperty((0,0,0,1))
        s_global = Window.size
        size_x = s_global[0]
        size_y = s_global[1]/3

    class MyWidget(BoxLayout):
        #init
        def __init__(self, **kwargs):
            super().__init__(**kwargs)
            ForeignLanguage = ColoredLabel(text="ForeignLanguage", size_hint=(None, None), background_color=(0/255,171/255,169/255, 1))
            Translation = ColoredLabel(text="Translation", size_hint=(None, None), background_color=(45/255,137/255,239/255, 1))
            Example = ColoredLabel(text="Example", size_hint=(None, None), background_color=(43/255,87/255,151/255, 1))
            verticalBox     = BoxLayout(orientation='vertical')
            verticalBox.add_widget(ForeignLanguage)
            verticalBox.add_widget(Translation)
            verticalBox.add_widget(Example)
            self.add_widget(verticalBox)

    class BoxLayoutDemo(App):
        def build(self):
            return MyWidget()

    if __name__ == '__main__':
        BoxLayoutDemo().run()
```

Comment: What issue do you hvae with updating the size of the label?

Comment: @inclement I have to hardcode size_y in the class ColoredLabel. But I would like to adapt size_x and size_y when I use "ForeignLanguage = ColoredLabel(...,size_x = a and size_y = b)"

Answer (score 1, accepted):

## Question 1

> How can this code be adapted so that I can define the size of the
>   certain label via a variable, rather than hard code it. Best would be
>   if we could come up with a solution like this:
>
> ```
> ForeignLanguage = ColoredLabel(..., size = (a,b))
> ```

### Answer

Just have the following design in your kv file. With the inheritance of Label widget, all the attributes defined will be available e.g. `size`, `size_hint`, `color`, `markup` etc.

#### Snippets - kv file

```
<ColoredLabel>:
    canvas.before:
        Color:
            rgba: root.background_color
        Rectangle:
            pos: self.pos
            size: self.size
```

## Question 2

> My code appears quite complicated to me. Is it possible to set the
>   background color of a label in a more easy way, like Label(...,
>   background_color = (1,1,1,1))?

### Answer

Your code looked fine.

#### Snippets - py file

```
    ForeignLanguage = ColoredLabel(text="ForeignLanguage", size_hint=(None, None), size=(300, 40),
                                   background_color=(1, 0, 0, 1))
    Translation = ColoredLabel(text="Translation", size_hint=(None, None), size=(100, 30),
                               background_color=(0, 1, 0, 1))
    Example = ColoredLabel(text="Example", size_hint=(None, None), size=(200, 20),
                           background_color=(0, 0, 1,  1))
```

## Output

[image: Result]